# Error when trying to install the deb pkg on Ubuntu for Ambari 2.4.2

Tags: ambari

I spent a great deal of time to get 2.4.2 to build on Ubuntu. I now have a .deb file in my target folder.

When i try to install it I get the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i target/ambari_2.4.2.0.0_all.deb

dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 5 package 'ambari:i386 amd64':
 'i386 amd64' is not a valid architecture name: character ' ' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-')
dpkg: error processing archive target/ambari_2.4.2.0.0_all.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386 amd64) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 target/ambari_2.4.2.0.0_all.deb
```